# Ruby - Get all referenced classes within a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

```
class DbExample < ApplicationRecord
end

module MyModule
  class Example
  
    def my_method
      DbExample.where(....)
    end

  end
end
```

I have a large code base where I call active record in a lot of places.  I was wondering:

Is it was possible to find all the occurrences where ApplicationRecord is being called?

I have seen `mod.constants` to get all classes in a module but I need to find all external classes called inside a class.

Comment: `ApplicationRecord` being "called" means what in this context? Used as an ancestor? You can check which [`subclasses`](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/class#method-i-subclasses) have been defined.

Comment: Is there a way to inspect the Example class and know about DbExample?

Comment: What relationship do these two have, other than a method of `Example` incidentally calling some method on `DbExample`? Static code analysis will only get you so far here, even if that could work, as a lot of things can be derived dynamically.

Comment: They don't have any relationship.  I was attempting to do some analysis on these types of things.

Comment: There's two approaches here: Static code analysis, even something as simple as `git grep`, more elegantly with [a parser](https://github.com/seattlerb/ruby2ruby), or dynamic analysis, as in wrapping all method calls in `DbExample` with something that logs `caller`.